# Will this mixed size RAM configuration work? Xeon 56xx ECC

Tags: memory

This image show valid/invalid configurations according to IBM:
[image]

Will this configuration pictured here work as well? This diagram is mine:
[image]

Exact configuration:

- CPU 1: 3x 16GB 1600MHz Dual Rank
- CPU 2: 6x 8GB 1333MHz Dual Rank

Here is a link to the [whitepaper](http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?infotype=SA&subtype=WH&htmlfid=XSW03075USEN) for context.

Comment: Can you link to the article where you found that so we can have some context? It looks like anything that adds up to 1.0 works, but you haven't given any information on how to do the calculation.

Comment: Google "Understanding Intel Xeon 5600
Series Memory Performance
and Optimization in IBM
System x and BladeCenter
Platforms
Ganesh" apparently i am out of links that i can post.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what actual server and memory you're planning on using but given what you have that seems ok for a 56xx series box.

Comment: I added more info to my post, they are all dual rank, and I am hoping 1600MHz will clock down to 1333MHz without a problem.

Comment: From one of your references "DDR3 DIMM Speed : DDR3 memory will be available in various capacities at 1333MHz and 1066MHz. The memory 
speed determines the maximum capability of the DIMM and can be clocked down to lower speeds. For example, a 1333MHz DIMM can be clocked down to 1066MHz or 800MHz in system settings. This can be done to save power."